# How to extract database from Filemaker runtime solution .FMPUR file?

Tags: database, windows, encryption, filemaker

I have a Windows installer EXE file made with Filemaker, when installed it deploys system files and a .FMPUR file. I am sure all relational data is in this file because if this file is opened in Filemaker it runs like normal installed application.

How can I reverse engineer it to extract or export its database to something like Excel, CSV or MySql.

[This question](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/5996/extracting-data-from-filemaker-application) is similar but it is discussing about some .USR which don't exist in my case and it is not giving a valid solution. In some Filemaker forum I read .FMPUR file is just renamed .FMP12 file so I tried to rename the extension but still it runs normal but don't see underlying database.

Comment: Have you tried simply renaming the EXE to ZIP?

Comment: Yes no success at all, renamed both fmpur and exe

Answer (score 2):

> In some Filemaker forum I read .FMPUR file is just renamed .FMP12 file

That is essentially correct. A runtime solution file can be opened in the FileMaker application just like any other solution file.

> I tried to rename the extension but still it runs normal but don't see
>   underlying database.

Not sure what exactly you want to "see". If you have full-access privileges, you can open `File > Manage > Database` and see how the file is structured.

You can extract *data* by exporting it - again, provided the account you use to log into the file has the privilege to do so.

Comment: No there are no such options for https://www.dropbox.com/s/hia9t2ehen42nna/University%20of%20Texas%202016.zip?dl=0

Comment: Stack Overlow is a Q&A site. If you want to have a discussion that may involve exchange of files, join one the forums dedicated to the FileMaker platform. Although I strongly suspect the conclusion will be the same: you need to speak to the solution's author.